# How do I test javascript that involves clicking a html file input element?

Tags: javascript, html, file, testing, jasmine

I'm writing some jasmine unit tests around a file upload workflow.

I want to test the javascript reaction to a user cancelling the selection dialog, I also want to test the javascript reaction to a user selecting files.

I'm not aware of any way of interacting with the dialog via javascript.

Do I need to stub out the input entirely, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I came up against this very problem recently. My own research led me to believe there is no event or method that allows you to interact with the file selection dialog in any way, nor detect that it has displayed or cancelled. I ended up fabricating the "change" event directly using jQuery to test as much of my code as I could.